# Getting number from row using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, cut

I have file with rows which looks like that:

```
xx_1: 2414 xx_4: 34214 xx_3: 4214 xx_2: 21421
xx_2: 1212 xx_1: 2424 xx_3: 23213 xx_4: 25214
...
```

I am using this command to get specific value( eg value of xx_3: from first row):

```
cat results.txt | head -n 1| sed -e 's/[xx_]//g' | sed  's/\(3:.*\):/_\1_/g' | cut -d"_" -f2  | awk '{print $2}'
```

Except that it looks like terrible it is not working for last element( like xx_2). Any ideas why?

**EDIT**

Sorry for being imprecise. Calling my command is giving me result

```
cat results.txt | head -n 1| sed -e 's/[IT_]//g' | sed  's/\(4:.*\):/_\1_/g' | cut -d"_" -f2  | awk '{print $2}'
34214
cat results.txt | head -n 1| sed -e 's/[IT_]//g' | sed  's/\(1:.*\):/_\1_/g' | cut -d"_" -f2  | awk '{print $2}'
2414
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sed expression is trying to match two colons, ":.*:", so it doesn't work for the last element. If you know your elements are numbers, you can change the sed expression to be more specific:

```
s/\(2: [0-9]\+\)/_\1_/g
```

Or even to just match everything except a colon:

```
s/\(2: [^:]\+\)/_\1_/g
```

Comment: Don't just slap a plaster on it.. using six commands for such a trivial parse is crazy.

Comment: I find that remembering six simple commands is easier than remembering six uncommonly used parts of a large programming language. He could easily do this with any programming language that has good string operations, but unless he does string processing every day, it's going to be harder that way.

Comment: This can easily be done entirely with `sed`, `awk` and `grep` with only knowing of *two parts* as you put it, limiting the record and field. The OP's pipeline is full of redundancy and shows they don't understand what they are doing. A quick fix is not helpful in the longer run.

Comment: You're right. But I also find it's unhelpful when people try to rewrite code instead of answering a simple question. We don't know if this is a simplification of a bigger case and if there's a reason he wrote it the way it is. A rewrite is still useful, as long as somebody performs the essential function of telling the OP what's wrong and how to change it. I'm performing the latter, and anybody else is free to do the former.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -Po 'xx_3: \K[^[:space:]]*' foo.input
4214
23213

$ grep -Po 'xx_2: \K[^[:space:]]*' foo.input
21421
1212
```

From there you can use `sed`/`awk` to retrieve specific lines, or use `head` in front of the `grep` if you only care about the first line.

Comment: Or just by using the `-m` option.

Comment: @sudo_O With `-m<n>` you get `n` lines, not 1. But yes, it can replace the `head`.

Comment: Using `-m 1` is equivalent to piping to `head -n 1`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want the *selector* `xx_3:` but this prints the number after it.

```
sed 's/.*\(xx_3:.\)\([0-9]*\).*/\2/g' results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for xx_3, print the next field, exit. No loop that slows it down:

```
awk '/xx_3/ {f=NR} f&&NR-1==f {print;exit}' RS=" " results.txt
4214
```

This can be used to print any next filed after search hit.